# Using for loops to produce decreasing lengths of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a particular function:

```
def create4(n):
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        output.append(range(1+i,1))
    return output
```

I want it to produce

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2],[1]]
```

for when I `print create4(5)`. How would I change my for loop make the code produce the desired output?

Comment: Looks like a homework?

Comment: @alKid look at his profil and you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use range(a,b,-1) to count down from a to b.

```
def func(n) :
    output = []
    for i in range(n+1,1,-1):
        output.append(range(1,i))
    return output 

print func(4)
```

In order to print [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4] ... [4]]:

```
def func(n) :
    output = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        output.append(range(i,n+1))
    return output 

print func(4)
```

Comment: What if I want to produce [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5]]?

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments of `range` out of order within your for loop. `range(m, n)` will give you the range of integers *x* where *m ≤ x < n*.

Also note that while this does what you want under python 2.7, in python 3.x they've changed range to always return an iterator. To be on the safe side, wrap each call to `range` in a `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create4(n):
    return sorted([range(1,x) for x in xrange(2,n+2)], reverse=True)
```